# Inverse of bubbling: prevent click on DOM children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I understand how bubbling and `event.stopPropagation()` works, but I'm looking for a way to avoid click handlers on all children of a DOM node.

```
<div onclick="console.log('LOG ME')">
  <div onclick="console.log('DO NOT LOG ME')">Click me</div>
</div>
```

I want 'LOG ME' to be logged, but 'DO NOT LOG ME' not to be logged.

I found a CSS way using `pointer-events: none`, works well, however, all my :hover, :focus CSS styles are gone on the child div.

Any ideas?

Edit: Some context. I'm using React. The outer div is a HOC, the inner one is a visible component. I want the HOC to catch all clicks of the child component, and stop click propagation into the child. In React would do:

```
const HOC = ChildComponent => class extends Component {
  handleClick = event => { /* Do what with event? */ }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Where `ChildComponent` is a clickable component

Comment: What is your use case for needing the inner listener in the first place?

Comment: I'm using React. The outer div is a HOC, the inner one is a visible component. I want the HOC to catch all clicks of the child component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update (for updated question)**

If you are using react then use the `Capture` at the end of the event so the handler is triggered on the capture phase. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events)

So something like

```
const HOC = ChildComponent => class extends Component {
  handleClick = event => { 
     /* Do what with event? */
     event.stopPropagation();
     /*the rest of the code you want for handling the click*/
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClickCapture={this.handleClick}>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

---

You need to stop the propagation on the event, and you need to use the capture phase of the event, not the bubble.

So instead of using the `onclick` use the [proper way to attach event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and for the outer one which you want to be the container use `true` as the 3rd parameter (*the `useCapture` parameter*)

```js
document.querySelector('.outer').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('LOG ME')
}, true);

document.querySelector('.inner').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('DO NOT LOG ME')
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just realized my question is more specific. I edited the original question, and added the "React" tag.

Comment: @amaurymartiny updated answer. Basically use `onClickCapture` instead of `onClick` and use the `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the capture phase of the event to hook into the click at the parent and stop the propagation to the children.

You should also follow [modern standards for event registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [not use inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991).

```js
// Normally, the following would set up event handler that bubbles up through all div elements
// but, you will see that it only fires once, for the parent element...
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  
    console.log(this);
    evt.stopPropagation();  // Don't allow the event
    
  }, true); // Adding the 3rd argument of true causes the event handler to be registered during the capture phase
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just realized my question is more specific. I edited the original question, and added the "React" tag.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be applicable to your situation but given the example of nested inline `onclick` you can remove the nested `onclick` attribute and event handler won't get called

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[onclick] [onclick]')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.removeAttribute('onclick')
})
```

```html
<div onclick="console.log('LOG ME')">
  <div onclick="console.log('DO NOT LOG ME')">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't apply to my case. I edited the original question.